# How to get frequency counts of unique values in a list using UNIX?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file that has a couple thousand domain names in a list. I easily generated a list of just the unique names using the uniq command. Now, I want to go through and find how many times each of the items in the uniques list appears in the original, non-unique list. I thought this should be pretty easy to do with this loop, but I'm running into trouble:

```
for name in 'cat uniques.list'; do grep -c $name original.list; done > output.file
```

For some reason, it's spitting out a result that shows some count of something (honestly not sure what) for the uniques file and the original file.

I feel like I'm overlooking something really simple here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you simply `sort original.list | uniq -c`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use `uniq -c` on your file :

> -c, --count
>           prefix lines by the number of occurrences

The command to get the final output :

> sort original.list | uniq -c

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work. I get counts, but still some names are listed multiple times with different counts, as if it didn't count every instance. Perhaps this is a product of the large file length?

Comment: Are you sure there are no spaces in those ? (eg "abc " != "abc")